# Nexus manager, npm 401 Unauthorized

Tags: npm, nexus

I'm trying to set up a nexus repository manager.

I have 3 npm repositories, private, proxy and a group of both (see images). Also I attached role's privileges and this is my .npmrc file:

```
registry = http://127.0.0.1:8081/repository/npm-group/
email = user@mail.com
always-auth = true
_auth = ZGV2OjEyMzQ1Ng==
```

When I try to do a "npm install" I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized: gulp-twig@^0.5.0
```

Without nexus, install ends successfully. I'm using this [project template.](https://github.com/zualex/frontend-template)

Any idea? What I'm missing?

[Private repository[image: Private repo]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18Lat.png)

[Proxy repository[image: Proxy repo]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T42sA.png)

[Group repository[image: Group repo]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E86nY.png)

[Privileges[image: Privileges]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxgEh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug on my npm version (5.0.3), already fixed.

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16528